# File transfer C++

Tags: c++, file-transfer, winsock2

When my client sends a file to the server, should I Sleep(100) or so before sending the next chunk to ensure the server has enough time to download + write the data?

Does that just seem completely unnecessary?

Also I'm getting wouldblock errors (# 10035) when sending a chunk, so im just looping send until it succeeds, if send == SOCKET_ERROR goto SendAgain; , is that ok?

Comment: If all you're doing with the block error is looping, why are you using a nonblocking socket in the first place?

Comment: Reading the latest comment about Select

Comment: If the socket is not in nonblocking mode, then `send` shouldn't return a wouldblock error, it should block in that scenario.

Comment: I mean't i am using nonblocking sockets, but your reply wasn't helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending your file via TCP, then it's the protocol that is ensuring that everything has been received, I wouldn't put a sleep between each chunk.

The wouldblock error is either that you're sending too much data for your output buffer, or you try to send it too quickly, and the remote buffer gets full. That seems ok to send it again because the receiver received it but didn't have enough space to store it and have juste drop it.

Here is a small article about your error: [Winsock error 10035](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2005/07/20/WinsockError10035.aspx)

Comment: So if it's either reason, looping the send works fine right? How come locally all is fine, but remotely it seems I'll drop some data somewhere

Comment: if the buffer is full and some data is dropped, you may not receive the data in the correct order. You can add a checksum (SHA-1/MD5/...) of your file that you send before sending the actual file. At the end you could be sure to have received the correct entire file.

Comment: I know I'm losing data cause the filesize is a lot smaller, the icon isn't there, the file won't open, etc. How can I prevent data from being dropped ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion using sleepfunction to wait for something to be done is in 99% of the time the wrong way.
You ll never now the time you gonna need or you ve to expect for a process to be executed (can be interrupted by e.g spikes, other problems in i/o or whatever)

If you want to make sure something important is executed completely you should read about Semaphores or something like that, where you lock/free processes on start/end.

Comment: I'll look into that, I've wanted to look for a sleep alternative, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to know more about this kind of process handling, the topic of priority sheduling should catch your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from a [man-page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html):

> When the message does not fit into the send buffer of the socket,
>   send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in
>   nonblocking I/O mode. In nonblocking mode it would fail with the error
>   EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in this case.  The [select(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) call may be
>   used to determine when it is possible to send more data.